# Ruby on Rails - Edit not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I have 3 models USER, EXPERT, HELPEE as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I am using devise on the user model.

Relationships

```
class Expert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

class Helpee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :expert
  has_one :helpee
```

I am using the following code for registration which works perfectly fine:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, :class => "form-control" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :class => "form-control" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "form-control" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => "form-control" %></div>
  <br>

  <div><%= f.hidden_field :role, value: "helpee" %><br />

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign Up" , :class => "btn btn-primary"%></div>
<% end %>
```

But this same logic is not working for EDIT.

Could you suggest how to create the EDIT form ?

Comment: `same logic is not working for EDIT`? How is it not working? What have you tried? You already get a ready-made edit page from Devise? Where is the problem?

Comment: `registration_path(resource_name)` => You are supposed to pass an instance of the resource to the URL helper, not the resource name. Give it a record already having an id and it should update it

Comment: @MrYoshiji `registration_path(resource_name)` is correct way in Devise . See Devise Registration form for edit https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/aea82d0b03a8aa150be8f692bf880d140e477d2e/app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb

Comment: @KirtiThorat Oh I see, I should use Devise some times ... Hey did you know you are #4 of all Stackoverflow reputation gains in this month? see http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2014-04-01/1012097#1012097 (2,535 month reputation) : Congratulations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote:

> sorry for this really long series of queries, I have tried feeding the
>   current password but still the changes are not being registered though
>   I am getting a success alert message –  samikb 14 hours ago

/End Quote

Can't add a comment, so responding here.
Check your application controller. Since your signup process is working, you should have a method for Sanitized Parameters there for signup. Something like this:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
```

Make sure you also have a similar one for update.
Something like this:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the shared view in the question which you initially used for `registration` and you are using the same logic for your `edit` form then you need to use form_for as below:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
```

You need to supply `method: :put` for it to work on EDIT.

**NOTE:**

With this logic, you cannot use same `form_for` definition for both `create` and `edit`. What it means is that you must have two separate views, one dealing with new registrations and other for editing existing registration.

Comment: Thanks Kirti. I tried this from /helpees/id/edit but it takes me to localhost:3000/users with the error "Current password can't be blank" and then shows me a form with Email, Password and Password confirmation fields. I assume this is some behaviour caused by devise, not sure what is causing this or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. Also, I am doing this in a different view built for EDIT and not in the registration view.

Comment: With devise, if you are trying to update a user record then its mandatory to key in the current password. This is default behavior on edit page. If you want to update a user record without password then follow guidelines here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Comment: this is my edit form http://imgur.com/m1Zeqn8. After I put in changes, it goes to this: http://imgur.com/Dr43uoi. Do I need to add another devise-specific 'current password' field or something on my edit form for it to work?

Comment: These fields are for setting up a `new password` and `password confirmation`. You need another field to input `current_passowrd`. Refer to Devise edit registration view https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb

Comment: i added the following code for current password, yet the values are not being saved : <div><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

Comment: You need to key in the current password of user in current_password textfield and after that submit the form.

Comment: sorry for this really long series of queries, I have tried feeding the current password but still the changes are not being registered though I am getting a success alert message